# Sort by birthdays

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How do I order it by their birthdays? Years don't matter.

```
DELIMITER //
Create procedure radnicipodatumu(IN ulaz_date date)
Begin 
select fname, lname, date_format(bdate, '%d.%m.%Y') as 'b_day', salary, bonus, state from employee
where 
DAYOFMONTH(ulaz_date) = DAYOFMONTH(bdate)
OR MONTH(ulaz_date) = MONTH(bdate)
order by bdate;
end //
DELIMITER ;

call radnicipodatumu("2002-05-09");
```

Comment: What error did you get? This seems precise

Comment: It is, but it's not sorted by their birthdays. It's sorted by their birth dates.

Comment: Then order by  DAYOFMONTH(bdate). BTW is birthday sun-sat or 1-31

Comment: @P.Salmon it's 1-31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format `bdate` to `MMDD` and use it in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(bdate, '%m%d')
```

or:

```
ORDER BY MONTH(bdate), DAY(bdate)
```